# Multiple OpenVPN server instances on a single machine

Tags: openvpn

I have a machine with two NICs both public facing with different IP addresses

Is it possible to have two instances of openVPN running and one using NIC1 and the other using NIC2?

Answer (score 0):

It is, assuming you have static IPs. You simply provide them what address they should listen on in their config file.

```
local a.b.c.d
```

*That line should be missing or commented out by default, causing the daemon to listen on all available interfaces.*

If your IPs are dynamically assigned, there is not built-in way that I know of, and you'll probably have to resort to updating the config file in ifupdown scripts.